# Pagination with categories php

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

In my site i have a gallery with categories and pagination.
But when i click to go to the second page it doesn't loads my category in the next page

my pagination code

```
<?php 

include '../includes/conn_cms.php';
$per_page = 8;
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$page = $_GET['page'];
}else{
    $page = 1 ;
    }
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;    
?>
```

this code loads my page with my selected category.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE category = '$_GET[cat_name]' ORDER BY id   DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page ";
$run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
{
echo'...
```

and this is my pagination.

```
    .. <ul class="pagination">
   <?php
    $pagination_sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery";
    $run_pagination = mysqli_query($conn, $pagination_sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_pagination);
    $total_pages = ceil($count/$per_page);
    for($i=1;$i<=$total_pages;$i++){
    echo'<li><a href="categoria.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';  
    }
    ?>
    </ul>..
```

What i want to do is when i click on pg 2 it loads the second page with the category that i am on exmple.

I'm at the category Foods and i want to see the second page of foods.
Because per page it loads only 8 pictures from my category Foods.

what i have to do,so this can work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the category variable to your pagination.

Change this line:

```
echo'<li><a href="categoria.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
```

Into:

```
echo'<li><a href="categoria.php?page='.$i.(isset($_GET['cat_name']) ? '&cat_name='.$_GET['cat_name'] : '').'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
```

I added an `isset()` just to make sure you don't get an *undefined index* error if you view the list without setting a category.